# “Messed up” an experience

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose I am excited for a movie that will be releasing tomorrow but my friend  just told me plot spoilers.

I want to say that he "messed up" the experience that I was going to have.

What can I use instead of “messed up” which can be more convenient or appropriate?

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: Why do you think they are called **spoilers**?

Comment: I apologize for my subjectivity.I will keep it in mind for future posts.

Comment: He spoiled the movie.but saying he spoiled the experience,i don't know.it feels weird.

Comment: As suggested by another comment, the most natural verb is **spoiled**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ruined**

Example:

> He *ruined* the experience I was about to have

This term is a pretty known term. You can use this word to describe him messing up your experience.

See more [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ruined). Check out the verb section.